# Deleted a model manually, php artisan migrate gives and error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

So I just started playing around with Laravel 5.1. I created a model with migration named "teachers". Then I manually deleted the model file which was Teachers.php which contained the Teachers class. Now when I try to roll back I get the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Class 'CreateTeachersTable' not found
```

I tried `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan migrate:refresh` and `php artisan migrate:reset` but it keeps on giving above error. I just want to start afresh. How to reset everything?

Comment: this is my fault [Class 'CreateOauthIdentitiesTable' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687079/laravel-migrate-failed-php-artisan-migraterefresh-seed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. So I found the solution. So if you accidentally delete any model file or migrations file without using `php artisan migrate:rollback` the above command and any migrate command will cause problems. SO what you need to do is, delete all the tables manually from the database. I was using sqlite database and I deleted migrations, users, questions, teachers, password_resets all the tables that were generated by migrate command. Then I ran `composer dumpautoload`. Then I ran `php artisan migrate` command again after making changes to the files and everything was back to normal.
So basically deleting migrations table solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you `refresh` your migrations, Laravel looks at your `migrations` table and uses the values in there to load the migrations files to rollback.

Since you manually deleted the migration file, it was never removed from your `migrations` table. You'll have to manually delete the row in that table for the given migration file.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if that class is still referenced somewhere by doing a full search within your project folder, and then if it is not, try running:

`php artisan clear-compiled`

Comment: Tried above command. Actually I read somewhere to drop the table so I have even dropped the table from database to start afresh. I ran above command. But now it still gives same error. And when I try to just use `php artisan migrate` it says "Nothing to migrate"

Comment: But have you searched in your project folder for the class? Maybe you you forgot a reference to the class somewhere?